# Number of different cycles in cyclic codes with length n

Tags: coding-theory

I am studying Information theory, coding theory in particular at the moment, and I am having trouble determining how many different cycles are defined by a certain generator polinomial?

Given a polinomial, for example $g(p)=p^6+p^3+1$, and the length of the code $n = 9$ how can I determine the number of different cycles that are defined? Everything is in modulo 2 arithmetics.

I know that the cycles (001)(010)(100) and (011)(110)(101) are defined, but how can I find the rest of them?

I also wonder if there is an explicit formula that can return me the result, maybe based on the different powers in the generating polinomial?

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: please specify that your code is binary. your cycle notation is nonstandard. are those codewords?

Comment: Cross posted in [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298374/11619).